# MeteorJs RouteController 'HomeController' is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am trying eventedmind 'em' tool for creation of project. I used 'em' to create a route. 'em' created a route in '/both/router/routes.js', a '/client/controllers/home.js as HomeController and '/client/views/home' folder with html css and js files.

The error can be removed it I place 'controllers' folder at root of project or in 'both' folder But leaving 'controllers' folder at its default location (in client folder), application gives error.

Error :

```
RouteController 'HomeController' is not defined.
at resolve (packages/iron:router/lib/route.js:91)
at Function.Route.findControllerConstructor (packages/iron:router/lib/route.js:113)
at Function.Route.createController (packages/iron:router/lib/route.js:131)
at Function.Router.createController (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:185)
at Function.Router.dispatch (packages/iron:router/lib/router_server.js:29)
at Object.router (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:15)
at next (/home/david/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.1.4.1hc4z6t++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Function.app.handle (/home/david/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.1.4.1hc4z6t++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
at Object.fn [as handle] (/home/david/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.1.4.1hc4z6t++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:74:14)
at next (/home/david/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.1.4.1hc4z6t++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

Can someone guide me what is wrong and how it can be rectified without changing folders location.

Comment: please share the `em` command you used to create the route and your home.js code

Comment: @Rajanand02 I have used em g:route home  and it showed success message.